# dc.js rowChart: stop yAxis from appearing in center of chart when all values are 0

Tags: dc.js

If I have a row chart:

[image]

And I add filters that remove all the data so that all group values are 0. The yAxis of the chart moves into the center:

[image]

Am I able to keep the 0 point of the yAxis to the left hand edge of the chart when the values are zero.

(also, I am using labelOffsetX() in these examples, but the behaviour is exactly the same when creating a rowChart with the minimum height, width, dimension and group properties.

I would like to avoid having to set the x() property manually.

Comment: This resulted from a change in D3 5.8. Please see if the workaround in [this issue](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/1656) works for you. It is essentially the same issue affecting the Y axis of a line chart instead of the X axis of a row chart.